# How to Save Shared Preference Value in ClearData Application?[Android]

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In clear Data Android, Shared Preference is clear. I don't want it clear.

Comment: There is no way to do it - the button is there to allow user to delete ALL the data the app has created

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the app data, shared preferences will also be cleared, you have to store in your database or cloud.

Comment: Database? Databases are deleted, too

Comment: I am not talking about SQLite.

Comment: Ok so your answer is to store data in cloud or in cloud... As non local database is cloud,  too

Comment: my app isn't online

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick for that, it is not a normal way but works:

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:manageSpaceActivity=".ActivityOfMyChoice">
```

by adding this line to your manifest instead of "Clear Data" button for "Manage Space" which launches ActivityOfMyChoice will be shown, it calls your activity and the Activity and you can finish your activity there like this:

```
public class ActivityOfMyChoice extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        finish();

    }
}
```

for me, this method worked!
let me know about the result

for more info, if you want to save your data even after "clear data" you might use the database to save your data and save your database in a file out of your application place in the device.